# Background image overlaid by checkerboard

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

I wondering how could I achieve a design for front matter page with a background image overlaid by a checkerboard.

```
\documentclass[12pt,svgnames]{book}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% Title Page
\title{My Title Page}
\author{My Self}

\date{}

\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-a}}}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin = 0pt}
    \maketitle

\restoregeometry
\chapter{Chapter Title}
%
chapter text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: And what should the output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a `pic` with two `args`: length of the side (in cm) and color of the square.

In this way you can enjoy yourself choosing what you prefer:

```
\documentclass[12pt,svgnames]{book}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Title Page
\title{My Title Page}
\author{My Self}

\date{}
\newlength{\mydim}

\tikzset{%
    pics/chessboard/.style args={#1,#2}{code={%
            \setlength{\mydim}{#1cm}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\stepeven}{2*#1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\totx}{int(round(\paperwidth/\mydim))*#1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\toty}{int(round(\paperheight/\mydim))*#1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\stepodd}{(2*#1)+#1}       
            \foreach \x in {0,\stepeven,...,\totx} \foreach \y in {0,\stepeven,...,\toty}
            {
                \path[fill=#2] (\x,\y) rectangle ++ (#1,#1);
            }
            \foreach \x in {#1,\stepodd,...,\totx} \foreach \y in {#1,\stepodd,...,\toty}
            {
                \path[fill=#2] (\x,\y) rectangle ++ (#1,#1);
            }
    }}
}

\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}
    \put(0,0){% 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic {chessboard={.7,red}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
}}

\begin{document}
    \newgeometry{margin = 0pt}
    \maketitle

    \restoregeometry
    \chapter{Chapter Title}
    %
    chapter text.

\end{document}
```

This is the output of the MWE (`\pic {chessboard={.7,red}};`):

[image]

For example, if you put `\pic {chessboard={.4,green}};`, you'll get this:

[image]

Comment: This is almost what I was looking after. Can you make the "white" color totally transparent, so to uncover the background image? Also, checkerboard should cover the entire page, with squares a little thicker, say 2 or 3 cm each. Can you revise your answer?

Comment: @Marie-Eve See my renewed answer, please let me know if you like it!